# How to add custom css class to block wrapper

Tags: theming, blocks

I need to add custom css classes to several blocks (can be blocks from view, or facet api, etc).
Is there a way to do it without creating a template for every block?
It could be useful a theme function, or a hook, that should do something like:

```
 if ($var == 'block_name') {
   $class_custom = 'my-custom-class';
 }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a template function for this: [template_preprocess_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7).

Use `$variables['classes_array']` to add classes to the block.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Block class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) project for the matter.

> Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent  element of a block. Hooray for more powerful block theming!

Comment: I know that module, the problem is that has not support for features or generally a way to export configuration.